# getting timestamp error message using cursor.execute in python script

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

My code is to collect stock data and save it into a database, but after it gets the data I am getting an error trying to save it to the database.

code snippet is:
(failing at cursor.execute)

```
all_tickers = pd.read_sql("SELECT ticker, id FROM security", conn)
ticker_index = dict(all_tickers.to_dict('split')['data'])
tickers = list(ticker_index.keys())

start = dt.datetime(2018, 8, 8)
end = dt.datetime.now()

for ticker in tickers:
    # Download data
    df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)
    # Write to daily_price
    for row in df.itertuples():
        values = [YAHOO_VENDOR_ID, ticker_index[ticker]] + list(row)
        sql_two = "INSERT INTO daily_price (data_vendor_id,ticker_id, price_date, open_price, high_price, low_price, close_price, adj_close_price, volume) " + \
                  "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql_two, tuple(values))      #<--errorhere
```

Error message:

```
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

I've tried adjusting the start/end time because the 'timestamp' object makes me think it is something to do with the time I am passing, but I can't figure out what this should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think MySQL isn't liking the pandas Timestamp object, but I don't have MySQL to test it out on... and this is too verbose to leave in a comment.

Can you try replacing your `values` line with this?:

```
        values = [YAHOO_VENDOR_ID, ticker_index[ticker]] + 
                 [row[0].to_pydatetime()] + list(row[1:])
```

Comment: Seems to have worked, but I am now getting another error. I'm going to play around with it for a while and see if I cant get it working and will update.

Comment: @JasonMaynard: ok. Best of luck.